# flash of a popup in html

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hi I am a first year computer science student, and we have to do a project in html, I wanted to add a popup but having never done javascript and having done little css I don't know how to solve this problem: when the html page loads or the popup it closes it flashes and repeats the closing animation I don't want this to happen

The code for HTML is:

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/popup.css">
</head>
<script src="js/popup.js">
  </script>

<body>
<a id="myBtn">show popup</a>

<div class="modal modal-disabled" id="myModal">
  <div class="modal-content" style="height: 300px; width: 500px;">
    <span class="close"> close </span>
    <div class="corpo">
        <h2>popup</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

The code CSS is:

```
.modal {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 9999999;
  left: 10px;
  top: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;

}

.modal-disabled {
  -webkit-animation-name: modalClose;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-name: modalClose;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  top: -999999px;
}

/* chiusura */
@keyframes modalClose {
  0% {
    top: 10px;
  }
  99% {
    top: 10px;
  }
  100% {
    top: -999999px;
  }
}


/*stile contenuto*/
.modal-content {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 35%;
  height: 25%;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0 3px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
  border-radius:5px;
  color: darkgray;
  background-image: url(../img/generale/suggerimenti.jpg);
}
.modal-content p{
  text-align: left;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right:10px;
}


/*animazione di apertura*/
@keyframes animatetop {
  0% {
    left: -300px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    left: 1px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

/*animazione di chiusura*/
@keyframes animateclose {
  0% {
    left: 0;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    left: -300px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

/* animazione di chiusura */
.modal-disabled .modal-content {
  -webkit-animation-name: animateclose;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.9s;
  animation-name: animateclose;
  animation-duration: 0.9s;
  left: 0;
}

/*animazione di apertura*/
.modal-enabled .modal-content {
  -webkit-animation-name: animatetop;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.9s;
  animation-name: animatetop;
  animation-duration: 0.9s;
  right: 0;
}

/* bottone per chiudere */
.close {
  color: #cdcdcd;
  float: right;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-right:5px;
  padding-top:5px;


}
.close img{
  width: 35px;
}

.close:hover{

}
.close:focus {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

The code javascript is:

```
window.onload = function() {

  var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");
  var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");
  var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// immagine per chiudere
  var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// immaigne per aprire
  btn.onclick = function() {
    showPopup();
  }

// immagine per chiudere
  span.onclick = function() {
    hidePopup();
  }

  function showPopup()
  {
    modal.className="modal modal-enabled";
  }

  function hidePopup()
  {
    modal.className="modal modal-disabled";
  }



}
```

Thank you very much for your reply

Comment: Have a look at this tuto: Btw your js code is messy. https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_popup.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
window.onload = function() {

  var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");
  var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");
  var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// immagine per chiudere
  var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// immaigne per aprire
  btn.onclick = function() {
    showPopup();
  }

// immagine per chiudere
  span.onclick = function() {
    hidePopup();
  }

  function showPopup()
  {
    modal.className="modal modal-enabled";
  }

  function hidePopup()
  {
    modal.className="modal modal-disabled";
  }



}
```

```css
.modal {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 9999999;
  left: 10px;
  top: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}

.modal-disabled {
  -webkit-animation-name: modalClose;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-name: modalClose;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  top: -999999px;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition:visibility 0.9s linear;
}

/* chiusura */
@keyframes modalClose {
  0% {
    top: 10px;
  }
  99% {
    top: 10px;
  }
  100% {
    top: -999999px;
  }
}


/*stile contenuto*/
.modal-content {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 35%;
  height: 25%;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0 3px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
  border-radius:5px;
  color: darkgray;
  background-image: url(../img/generale/suggerimenti.jpg);
}
.modal-content p{
  text-align: left;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right:10px;
}


/*animazione di apertura*/
@keyframes animatetop {
  0% {
    left: -300px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    left: 1px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

/*animazione di chiusura*/
@keyframes animateclose {
  0% {
    left: 0;
    opacity: 1;
    
  }
  100% {
    left: -300px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

/* animazione di chiusura */
.modal-disabled .modal-content {
  -webkit-animation-name: animateclose;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.9s;
  animation-name: animateclose;
  animation-duration: 0.9s;
  left: 0;
}

/*animazione di apertura*/
.modal-enabled .modal-content {
  -webkit-animation-name: animatetop;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.9s;
  animation-name: animatetop;
  animation-duration: 0.9s;
  right: 0;
  transition:visibility 0.9s linear;
}

/* bottone per chiudere */
.close {
  color: #cdcdcd;
  float: right;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-right:5px;
  padding-top:5px;


}
.close img{
  width: 35px;
}

.close:hover{

}
.close:focus {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/popup.css">
</head>
<script src="js/popup.js">
  </script>

<body>
<a id="myBtn">show popup</a>

<div class="modal modal-disabled" id="myModal">
  <div class="modal-content" style="height: 300px; width: 500px;">
    <span class="close"> close </span>
    <div class="corpo">
        <h2>popup</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Something like this, I just added visibility for disabled class and a transition for it

Comment: Vote up if it helped!